# combine to jar (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Example:

> This theory also explains why cobalt, nickel and iron objects become magnetized after lying unmoved for years; their "molecule-magnets", subject to the earth's magnetic field for so long, are gradually pulled into line. Similarly, you can make a magnet by tapping an iron bolt while pointing it in the direction of the north magnetic pole because the tapping and the influence of the Earth's magnetic pole combine to **jar** the "molecule-magnets" of the bolt into line.

I do not understand how the verb *jar* is used here.

Comment: This is interesting. At first I though you didn't know that this *jar* is a verb, but it's clear that you know that. Does this mean that you couldn't find a definition that would make sense to you in dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To jar" describes the purpose of the verb "combine."

The tapping and the influence combine.  They combine for the purpose of jarring the "molecule-magnets."

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jar) has several meanings of "jar" as a verb. The second,

> to hit or shake (something) forcefully

is the appropriate usage. The "magnet-molecules" in the example bolt have been moved into line with some force, and that force is produced by tapping on the bolt.

As a side note, "jar" is one of those English words with several disparate meanings. A jar can be a small glass container whose top can be sealed, or it can be jolt or shaking. The adjective "ajar" means open, leading to the child's riddle,

> Question: When is a door not a door?
>
> Answer: When it's ajar.